# Has Stack Exchange data been used for expert finding yet?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I am trying to find some sources other than LinkedIn profiles that can be used for measuring the expertise of professionals at different careers. Do you think that Stack Exchange data is good for this purpose? Has it been used for such kind of tasks?

Answer (score 3):

> Do you think that Stack Exchange Data is good for this purpose?

Given that all the data there is stripped from any non-public identifying information, I doubt it.

> Has it been used for such kind of task?

Not that I know of, but... the Internet is a big place with many people and many happenings that I am not privy to.

But it really boils down to, for what purpose are you:

> trying to find some sources other than LinkedIn profile that can be used for measuring the expertise of professionals at different careers.

Depending on that, it might be useful for finding the information you are looking for (though, the [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) might be a more suitable source of data).